# python requests error

Tags: python, requests

В чём тут ошибка?
код:

```
import requests
poss = input('Ваш запрос: ')
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + poss + '&source=hp&ei=W8ikYqiPM72Uxc8Pocmb-AM&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYqTWa3qE4RVcXpD9DU37d-bM_dUylC9B&ved=0ahUKEwjoqO2R7qX4AhU9SvEDHaHkBj8Q4dUDCAY&uact=5&oq=ыав&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEAoyCggAELEDEIMBEAoyBAgAEAoyBQgAEIAEMgQIABAKMgcIABCABBAKMgcIABCABBAKMgQIABAKMgQIABAKMgcIABCABBAKOggIABCABBCxAzoLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6DAgAEIAEELEDEAoQAToICC4QgAQQ1AI6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOgUILhCABDoLCC4QgAQQChABECo6CQgAEIAEEAoQAVAAWJkBYN_RBmgBcAB4AIABbYgBogKSAQMyLjGYAQCgAQE&sclient=gws-wiz'
myobj = 'VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc lEBKkf'

x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)
print(x.text)
```

error

```
            Ваш запрос: sdf
    Ваш запрос: saf
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>405.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The request method <code>POST</code> is inappropriate for the URL <code>/search?q=saf&amp;source=hp&amp;ei=W8ikYqiPM72Uxc8Pocmb-AM&amp;iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYqTWa3qE4RVcXpD9DU37d-bM_dUylC9B&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjoqO2R7qX4AhU9SvEDHaHkBj8Q4dUDCAY&amp;uact=5&amp;oq=%D1%8B%D0%B0%D0%B2&amp;gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEAoyCggAELEDEIMBEAoyBAgAEAoyBQgAEIAEMgQIABAKMgcIABCABBAKMgcIABCABBAKMgQIABAKMgQIABAKMgcIABCABBAKOggIABCABBCxAzoLCC4QgAQQsQMQgwE6DAgAEIAEELEDEAoQAToICC4QgAQQ1AI6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOgUILhCABDoLCC4QgAQQChABECo6CQgAEIAEEAoQAVAAWJkBYN_RBmgBcAB4AIABbYgBogKSAQMyLjGYAQCgAQE&amp;sclient=gws-wiz</code>.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: Очевидно, в том, что некорректный URL. Любой URL должен начинаться с поддерживаемого клиентом протокола, например `https://`

Comment: @andreymal секундочку сейчас проверю не уходите

Comment: @andreymal ошибка стала еще больше

Comment: `https//:` — вы здесь белиберду какую-то непонятную написали

Comment: @andreymal простите я не знаю куда спешил

Comment: @andreymal ошибка всеравно пресудствует

Comment: `https://` должно быть, не там `:`

Comment: А во-вторых - что за данные то вы передаёте собственно? Почему это множество, состоящее из одной строки белиберды?

Comment: @CrazyElf в своем коде я правильно написал, ошибка только тут в посте, однако изменив на правельное у меня всеравно ошибка была

Comment: @CrazyElf в каком смысле?

Comment: @lolwqe ну значит измените пост так, чтобы он соответствовал реальности

Comment: там есть ссылка и название класса

Comment: @andreymal я нашел в чем ошибка но теперь она другая

Comment: Теперь ошибка говорит вам о том, что на указанный URL нельзя посылать POST-запрос, который вы зачем-то пытаетесь послать

Comment: @andreymal как его не отсылать?????????7

Comment: Ну, просто не запускайте этот код, и тогда никаких запросов отсылаться не будет ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за совет, но могу ли я эту защиту обойти?

Comment: Какую защиту? Вы просто зачем-то пытаетесь заставить гугловский сервер делать то, что он делать в принципе не умеет (и не должен уметь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests

poss = input('Ваш запрос: ')
url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={poss}'
x = requests.get(url)
print(x.text)
```

Comment: Это работает, но как сделать чтобы он получал текст из класса VwiC3b yXK7lf MUxGbd yDYNvb lyLwlc lEBKkf и выводил только его

Comment: Ну это уже другой вопрос не относящиеся к данному посту. Оформите новый вопрос.